# Can't understand results of pg_stat_statements view

Tags: postgresql, configuration, statistics, performance, performance-testing

I configured my postgresql.conf (my version is 9.1) with the normal persistent configuration:

```
shared_preload_libraries = 'pg_stat_statements,plperl'
custom_variable_classes = 'pg_stat_statements,plperl'
pg_stat_statements.max = 100
pg_stat_statements.track = all
pg_stat_statements.save = on
```

I let one month to run within a database which is constantly accessed with read/write queries.

After a month (or generally enough time to be sure lots of queries were executed) I do the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/pgstatstatements.html) query with top five slowest queries, and get this result:

```
-[ RECORD 1 ]---------------------------------------------------------------
query       | UPDATE XXXXXXXX
calls       | 63486
total_time  | 238.271792999997
rows        | 40740
hit_percent | 99.9938060778852878
-[ RECORD 2 ]---------------------------------------------------------------
query       | SELECT XXXXXXXX
calls       | 67347
total_time  | 0.852444000000713
rows        | 67347
hit_percent | 100.0000000000000
```

... and so on. I see the real number of `calls` as `total_time` is (very) much bigger for this queries than this view says. I don't understand how this works, because I expected hours in the total_time field as my server is running for more than 3 months without restarting.

In general is a no-change-from-doc configuration, and I get nonsense results.

Comment: The total time is the elapsed query time for the given query, not the time the database was up for. Thought it was obvious...

Answer (score 1):

I quote the manual ([at the page you are linking to, just for the appropriate  version 9.1](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/pgstatstatements.html))

> total_time ... Total time spent in the statement, in seconds

`67347 calls` totaling `0.852 seconds`. That's `0.012 ms` per call.
Not uncommon for a simple `SELECT`.

If that cannot explain it, consider this [quote from the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/pgstatstatements.html):

> Note that statements are considered the same if they have **the same
>   text**, regardless of the values of any out-of-line parameters used in
>   the statement. Using out-of-line parameters will help to group
>   statements together and may make the statistics more useful.

We'd have to study your exact statement(s) to assess that.

There is also the function [`pg_stat_statements_reset()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/pgstatstatements.html#AEN143035) to reset statistics (superusers only). Are you sure it wasn't called?

And there are a number of [configuration parameters](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/pgstatstatements.html#AEN143045) to regulate what is tracked. Any fancy settings there?

Comment: Its supposed to be the 2nd slower query on my box, and as I said, the server is running for 3 month, it's imposible that the 2nd query had only spent 0.82 seconds in 3 months.

Comment: I added a bit more to my answer. It's mostly guesswork, with the information we have here.